# Events in a Backbone view that can be added multiple times in the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Before explaining the problem I am facing,this is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/template" id="view_template">
            <li>
            <label class="lbl" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;"><%= name %></label>
            <button class="btn">Click</button>
            </li>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults : {
                    m_name : "Default name"
                },
                modify : function(value) {
                    this.set({
                        m_name : value
                    });
                }
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#add").click(function() {
                    var appModel = new AppModel();
                    appModel.modify($("#txt").val());
                    new CustomView({
                        model : appModel
                    });
                    $("#txt").val("");
                });
                CustomView = Backbone.View.extend({
                    el : $(".list"),
                    events : {
                        "click .btn" : "showAlert"
                    },
                    initialize : function() {
                        this.render();
                    },
                    render : function() {
                        var variables = {
                            name : this.model.get("m_name")
                        };
                        var t = _.template($("#view_template").html(), variables);
                        $(this.el).append(t);
                    },
                    showAlert : function() {
                        alert(this.model.get("m_name"));
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="txt"/>
        <button id="add">
            Add
        </button>
        <ul class="list" style="list-style: none"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

A demo is here - http://jsfiddle.net/jCekv/

You can type any value into textfield and click Add.The text will be added to a list which is a backbone view.You can keep on adding multiple values to the list.After adding some items,click on the Click button in any of the items in the list.I want to get the value in the model for that view.But because of the way I am adding `Events`,event handlers are getting executed multiple times.For eg:If i add 3 items and click on any of the buttons in the list 3 alerts will come-one corresponding to each of the items that is added.This is not the way I want.I want to have the event being triggered only for the Backbone View which has been clicked so that I get access to the model of the Backbone View I have clicked.

How I can achieve this functionality?.Please let me know if my question is not clear.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all your `CustomViews` have their element set to `$(".list")`. Therefore, all delegate events are added to the same DOM element, the list, and not the individual list items.

See a possible solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/mbuchetics/R8jPA/

I changed the `CustomView` to use a `tagName` of `li` instead of setting the element. The template is not appended to the element but instead its content is set. This way, each `CustomView` represents one item of the list and the click event refers to exactly that item.
I also removed the render call from initialize, instead the view is rendered when it is appended to the list (in the "add click" callback).
`Render()` returns `this` and therefore you can use `view.render().el` to get the list item's html.

You could further improve your application to use collections and a separate view for the collection. The collection view could then handle events such as "add" on the collection and update itself (and the individual item views) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're creating a new instance of the view class for each item, assigning the same DOM element (which corresponds to the whole list, not an individual item) to each instance, and registering the same event listener.  So each time you click any of the buttons, the event listener fires for each view object.

Something like this will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jCekv/1/

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

  $( "#add" ).click( function () {

    var appModel = new AppModel();

    appModel.modify( $( "#txt" ).val() );

    var item = new Item_View( {

      model : appModel

    } );

    list.add_item( item );

    $( "#txt" ).val( "" );

  } );


  var List_View = Backbone.View.extend( {

    el : $( ".list" ),

    events : {

      "click .btn" : "showAlert"

    },

    initialize : function () {

      this.render();

    },

    add_item : function ( item ) {

      item.render();

      item.$el.data( 'view_object', item );

      this.$el.append( item.el );

    },

    showAlert : function ( event ) {

      alert(

        $( event.target )

          .closest( 'li' )

          .data( 'view_object' )

          .model.get( "m_name" )

      );

    }

  } );


  var Item_View = Backbone.View.extend( {

    tagName : 'li',

    render : function() {

      var variables = {

        name : this.model.get( "m_name" )

      };

      var t = _.template( $( "#view_template" ).html(), variables );

      this.$el.html( $( t ).html() );

      return this;

    }

  } );


  var list = new List_View;

} );
```

- I created separate view classes for the list and for items.
- I'm storing a reference to the view object for each item using `jQuery.data`, so that the view object (and via that, the model object) can be retrieved inside the event listener (`showAlert`).  Alternatively you could maintain an array of the items' view objects in the list view.  I already have this setup to perform adding items through an `add_item` method of the list view, so that would facilitate maintaining such an array of item view objects.